# How to make multiple COUNT with different conditions in single select statement

Tags: sql, firebird

I made three selects below where each one returns a value. How do I do a select only and return the three values, each with its condition? All information is in one table.

```
SELECT COUNT (GRA_HRFIM) as "Conferidos antes 17h" FROM GRADE WHERE GRA_HRFIM < '17:00:00' AND GRA_DATADIGITA = '04/28/2021'

SELECT COUNT (GRA_HORADIGITA) as "Importados antes 17h" FROM GRADE WHERE GRA_HORADIGITA < '17:00:00' AND GRA_DATADIGITA = '04/28/2021'

SELECT COUNT (GRA_HRFIM) as "Total pedidos" FROM GRADE WHERE GRA_DATADIGITA = '04/28/2021'
```

Answer (score 6):

Condition `GRA_DATADIGITA = '04/28/2021'` is same for all the counts so use it in where clause. Now you have third count by simply selecting `COUNT (GRA_HRFIM)` but for the first and second count you need to use `case when` statement to select conditional count.

```
SELECT COUNT(case when GRA_HRFIM < '17:00:00' then GRA_HRFIM else null end)
         AS "Conferidos antes 17h",
       COUNT(case when GRA_HORADIGITA < '17:00:00' then GRA_HORADIGITA else null end)
         AS  "Importados antes 17h",
       COUNT(GRA_HRFIM)
         AS "Total pedidos"
  FROM GRADE
 WHERE GRA_DATADIGITA = '04/28/2021';
```

You can also avoid mentioning else part of case when statements since default value is null.

```
SELECT COUNT(case when GRA_HRFIM < '17:00:00' then GRA_HRFIM end)
             AS "Conferidos antes 17h",
           COUNT(case when GRA_HORADIGITA < '17:00:00' then GRA_HORADIGITA end)
             AS  "Importados antes 17h",
           COUNT(GRA_HRFIM)
             AS "Total pedidos"
      FROM GRADE
     WHERE GRA_DATADIGITA = '04/28/2021';
```

Comment: You can leave off the `else null`, as that is the default.

Comment: If to shorten the query text yet further then there can be one more optimization. Since we do usual `count( ...` rather than `count(distinct ...` the specific values do not matter and only nullness does. So query like `count(case when GRA_HRFIM < '17:00:00' then 1 end)` would work just the same, too :-)